# How to hide video.js player

Tags: hide, video.js

I am using video.js player and I am having some troubles with it.

I would like to hide the player when a button is clicked. Currently, I simply hide the video object (identified by its id) with JS by modifying the CSS property, the problem is that the controls bar stays visible, which is not proper.

So, what can I do to hide the player (and the control bar) after cliking on a button ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide control bar with this css

```
.vjs-control-bar { display:none!important; }
```

and click button for hide the player

```
<input type="button" id="hidevideo" onclick="hideVideo();" value="hide video">
```

javascript code

```
function hideVideo()
{
   var videoid =document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-control-bar");
   videoid[0].style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
}
```

Code on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wTeT9/1/

Comment: Btw. you don't need to write css. Just add the class "vjs-controls-disabled" to the video tag.